# Python Pyro4 has no attribute 'naming'

Tags: python, pyro

I am having trouble with Pyro 4 in Windows 10.

I installed Pyro4 via `pip`.

I open cmd and type `py`.

I type: `import Pyro4`.

I type: `Pyro4.naming`.

I get back `AttributeError: module 'Pyro4' has no attribute 'naming'`.

I type: `help(Pyro4)`.

`naming` is listed in the package contents.

Comment: "package contents" does not equal "module contents". You need to ``import Pyro4.naming`` to access that module, see DYZ answer below. This is basic Python import logic btw, it has nothing to do with Pyro as such.

Answer (score 4):

`naming` is a module and a part of the package `Pyro4`. It has to be imported separately:

```
import Pyro4.naming
```

Or:

```
import Pyro4.naming as naming
```

Comment: or `from Pyro4 import naming`

Comment: Actually it is imported with `import Pyro4`, see my answer bellow.

Comment: Since a few versions ago Pyro4 (the top level package) no longer imports anything from the Pyro4.naming package. It gets all it needs from Pyro4.core, mostly. Before that, it did import a few things from the naming sub package but it never import the full module. That is why you have to import it in your own code if you need to use things from it, if you only have imported Pyro4 before. (This is all basic Python import logic btw, it has nothing to do with Pyro as such.)

Answer (score 1):

Since `naming` is a module you cant just call it.

```
help(Pyro4.naming)
```

proves it is loaded module and it is working. 
You can access classes or functions in `naming` as

```
Pyro4.naming.AutoCleaner(...)
```

Comment: Pyro4.naming.AutoCleaner() results in "module 'Pyro4' has no attribute 'naming'"

Comment: help(Pyro4.naming) results in "module 'Pyro4' has no attribute 'naming'"